# Gradle: How to set version from custom plugin

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I've written a custom plugin (my first) which manages a "build number" which I want to include in the build.gradle "version" as so:

```
allprojects {
version = "1.2.3.${buildNumber}"
}
```

Unfortunately my plugin is never run and thus the buildNumber returned is "null".

Below is my build.gradle.

If I run "gradle showbuild" I see the right buildNumber.

If I run "gradle showInfo" the build number reported is "null".

Somehow I need to get gradle to call my plugin task 'buildInfoLoad' before the "version" value is set in allprojects.  Since I'm knew to gradle I am struggling with this.

Any pointers would be most appreciated!

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            // Access to MangoGrove
            url uri('../repo')
        }
        maven { // aka "jcenter()"
            url "https://jcenter.bintray.com"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        // Provide the "provided" and "optional" methods for dependencies
        classpath 'com.netflix.nebula:gradle-extra-configurations-plugin:3.0.3'

        classpath group: 'org.mangogrove.gradle',
                  name: 'MangoGrove',
                  version: '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.mangogrove.gradle'

task showbuild(dependsOn: 'buildInfoLoad') << {
    println("BI build number: $buildinfo.buildNumber")
    println("BI build time: $buildinfo.buildTime")
}

task createbuild(dependsOn: 'buildInfoCreate') << {
    println("BI build number: $buildinfo.buildNumber")
    println("BI build time: $buildinfo.buildTime")
}

allprojects {
    ext {
        buildNumber = "$buildinfo.buildNumber"
    }
    version = "1.0.0.${buildNumber}-alpha2"
    //version = "1.0.0.${buildinfo.buildNumber}-alpha2"

    apply plugin: 'eclipse'

    eclipse {
        classpath {
            downloadSources=true
            //downloadJavadoc=true
        }
    }

}

task showInfo << {
    println("Product Version is $version")  
    println("Product BuildNumber is $buildNumber")
}
```

Comment: What task in your plugin generated the version number? If your code is on a public repo like github, you can just link there

Comment: The 'buildInfoLoad' task loads the buildinfo.buildNumber and buildinfo.buildTime values.

Comment: Does your plugin have an apply function?

Comment: Yes, my plugin calls apply().  The plugin itself works fine if you run "gradle showbuild" or "gradle createbuild".  The trouble is that when I set the project "version" the plugin task "buildInfoLoad" has not yet been called.  Hence $buildinfo.buildNumber is not yet set.  So how do I tell gradle to run my 'buildInfoLoad' task before I set "version = "1.2.3.${buildinfo.buildNumber}"?

Comment: I ask about apply because, how about you set your build number in the apply() function? Apply happens when the plugin is applied, which I believe is rather early in the build lifecycle, certainly before you run any other tasks.

Comment: Setting version in my plugin apply via "project.setVersion(...)" is interesting.  Unfortunately it doesn't solve the issue.  If I do not set project.version in build.gradle then I get errors from 'java' plugin about version not being available.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, the `buildInfoLoad` task should really be a method instead which you can call from apply(). Is `buildInfoLoad` doing anything other than load properties for the rest of the gradle build to use?

Comment: Yes, the buildInfoLoad task loads the build number form a properties file.  That's all it does.